# IIS 8.5 Configuration causes an issue with Sitefinity 12.1 dynamic link creation (ASP.NET .NET 4.7.2)

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching, sitefinity

I'm running IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2. It's a test server and I have 3 sites running on it, Dev, QA, and Staging.

The issue is with QA. The ASP.NET Sitefinity application running there resolves the incorrect domain name when it dynamically creates links. Specifically it uses the www in the domain instead of qa. So, https://qa.myexamplesite.com is the desired link, but it creates https://www.myexamplesite.com.

There is a www.myexamplesite.com but it is hosted on a completely different machine. Also, the application code does not contain references to the domain.

Dev and Staging are working fine. I changed the physical path of QA to point to Dev, but QA is still broken. I changed the physical path of Dev to point to the QA application code, but Dev does not break - still works fine. At this point, I'm reasonably sure that there is a configuration issue in IIS but I've so far been unable to find it. I've also been unable to recreate the issue on my local machine.

Here are the configuration details from the ApplicationHost file ommiting any sensitive or non-pertinent information:

```
<applicationPools>
    <add name="DefaultAppPool" />
    <add name=".NET v4.5 Classic" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
    <add name=".NET v4.5" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
    <add name="dev.myexamplesite.com" autoStart="true" />
    <add name="staging.myexamplesite.com" autoStart="true" />
    <add name="qa.myexamplesite.com" />
    <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" />
    </applicationPoolDefaults>
</applicationPools>

  <sites>
        <site name="dev.myexamplesite.com" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="dev.myexamplesite.com">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="S:\Dev\myexamplesite" />
                <virtualDirectory path="/App_Data/Sitefinity/Search" physicalPath="S:\Dev\SitefinitySearch" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:dev.myexamplesite.com" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:dev.myexamplesite.com" sslFlags="0" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="staging.myexamplesite.com" id="3" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="staging.myexamplesite.com">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="S:\Staging\myexamplesite" />
                <virtualDirectory path="/App_Data/Sitefinity/Search" physicalPath="S:\Staging\SitefinitySearch" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:staging.myexamplesite.com" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:staging.myexamplesite.com" sslFlags="0" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="qa.myexamplesite.com" id="2" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="qa.myexamplesite.com">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="S:\QA\myexamplesite" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:qa.myexamplesite.com" sslFlags="0" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:qa.myexamplesite.com" />
            </bindings>
        </site>       
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

I've been working through the resources to try to find where this problem could exist. The application is using Sitefinity propietary methods to dynamically create the links, so I've been unable to pin down exactly what method they are using. Here is some of the weird behavior I've been able to document.

I can refresh IIS, flushdns etc but the behavior does not change. I've restarted the server but the issue remains.

After a refresh, if I navigate to the site using a browser on the server then the URLs resolve correctly consistently. If I navigate to the site from an incognito browser then similarly the URLs are correct UNTIL I reload a few times, usually by the second or third page load the URLs are incorrect again. This is true regardless of the browser I'm using.

It seems like an IIS caching issue - but I can't track down where this is configured. There is no configured output caching that I can detect.

(aside) If it's helpful - the application code is calling this method from the open sourced Sitefinity library feather:
https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend/Mvc/Helpers/HyperLinkHelpers.cs

It's specifically calling GetFullPageUrl (line 149). However, I found this of limited use since it calls UrlPath which is a member of the proprietary Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.

I appreciate any insight, resources, direction, thoughts or rebukes on this problem. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you go to Administration > Settings > Advanced > System > Site URL Settings 
and see if Enable non-default Site URL Settings is checked and if the Host field is hard-coded to any of the other sites.

If so, you may want to correct it.

Comment: This is a thing that I did do already and there were no non-default sites hard coded within. I would prefer if this were a Sitefinity configuration issue as it could be fixed from settings easily, but what makes me think it is not is that

1) Changing the IIS physical path to a completely different "working" code base does not resolve the issue
2) Changing the IIS phsyical path for the dev instance to the "not working" qa instance does not cause dev to have the issue

Upvoting since this will be the answer for the vast majority of people who will have a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I want to partially credit [Veselin Vasilev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438780/veselin-vasilev) since he was on the right track. So here's what happened and how we fixed it.

At the time the error had started to occur we had another Sitefinity instance running and pointed to the QA db. Sitefinity, for some reason, started referring to a piece of db configuration after this event. It's not clear what this trigger was precisely, or what allowed it to work so long prior to that event with this incorrect information.

The db configuration in question is a table called sf_sites. There is an entry called live_url that must be changed in order to fix this. We had restored a production instance of Sitefinity in our test environments to test a Sitefinity upgrade, not knowing that the Sitefinity db kept domain name records.

The configuration that Veselin was talking about overrides that live_url property (although I could never get that override to work properly). What's odd is that we had restored over the test db with production db months ago and were never presented with an issue. It wasn't until we had multiple sites hitting the same db that the issue presented and even after removing the second site would not go away.

Anyway, updating the sf_sites table is what did the trick. Please add this to your check list if you need to copy one environment's Sitefinity db into a new environment.

Comment: Oh, so it was a multi-site instance. You can actually change the live url from the Sitefinity UI, no need to manually update the database.

Comment: We had not intended it to be a multi site instance - but another person was testing a feature and chose to spin up a different IIS instance and point it at the same db - but yeah that certainly did it. Thank you for your help Veselin